# Will adding an annotation break Java Serialization?

Tags: java, serialization, annotations

I am in the process of rewriting a very old java app to Spring Boot and Hibernate 5.  Part of this task requires that I replace our XML configuration (both Spring and Hibernate) with annotations.

I have the following question.  Let's assume that the application contains a class as such:

```
public class MyObject implements Serializable {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 81848571841847187L;
      private String id;
      private String name;
      //getters and setters...
}
```

This class Serialized across a network, and is included in a "common" jar, which classers must include, in order to deserialize on their end.

Let's assume that I add a few Hibernate and JPA annotations to the class

```
@Table(...)
@Entity
public class MyObject implements Serializable {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 81848571841847187L;

      @Id
      @Column(...)
      private String id;

      @Column(...)
      private String name;
      //getters and setters...
}
```

My question is:  if the caller (who deserializes the above Object) does *not* have those annotations in his classpath, will serialization fail?

Answer (score 1):

Only Annotations with RETENTION=RUNTIME used in byte code, but Serialization works with object fields, not with classes.

but its important to understand that Annotations can be used by custom serializer.
for example this is how @Transient exclusion is implemented.

so the next thing is to check what type of Serialization mechanism is used.

elad